# Why do <%=%> tags render as &quot;&lt;%=%>&quot;?

Tags: asp.net

I have an input control on a page  like this:

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    causesvalidation="false"
    runat="server" 
    id="resetButton"  
    value="Iptal" 
    onclick='return  
    resetForm("<%=projectValidationSummary.ClientID%>");' />
```

when it is rendered

```
<input 
    name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EditForm$resetButton" 
    type="button" 
    id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EditForm_resetButton" 
    value="Iptal" 
    onclick="return  resetForm(&quot;&lt;%=projectValidationSummary.ClientID%>&quot;);" />
```

I use `<%=%>` tags on page but it is rendered as

```
&quot;&lt;%=%>&quot;
```

Can anyone tell my why this is happening?

Comment: Is your input a <asp:button /> or a <input type="button" /> control?

Comment: I think question might have different answers depending on what you are trying to do. Is this a JavaScript, JSP or ASP?

Comment: it's asp.net page and <input control that has runat server specification.,i also  tried andrew's idea but no change happended:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<%= %> is only usable inside literal html and can't be used on a server controls attribute.

Instead you should us databinding <%# %>, and in your case i think you are trying to trigger a javascript function on your client side and then your code should look like this:

```
<asp:button
causesvalidation="false"
runat="server"
id="resetButton"
text="Iptal"
onclientclick='<%# String.Format("return resetForm(\"{0}\");", projectValidationSummary.ClientID) %>' />
```

and on the server side you should bind the attribute with this code (probably in the Page.Load event):

```
if(!this.IsPostBack)
{
  this.resetButton.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thnx for our helps
i made js function  "resetForm" non parameter 
and  i got item's clientId inside javascript function in this case...

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix and match render blocks with text for values. Try this

```
onclick='<%= "return resetForm(\"" + projectValidationSummary.ClientID + "\");" %>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `runat="server"` - you don't need it if you're doing a literal write (`<%=`)

So:

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  causesvalidation="false"
  id="resetButton"  
  value="Iptal" 
  onclick="return resetForm('<%= projectValidationSummary.ClientID %>');" />
```

Or use a databind instead:

```
<input 
  type="button" 
  causesvalidation="false"
  id="resetButton"  
  runat="server"
  value="Iptal" 
  onclientclick="return resetForm('<%# projectValidationSummary.ClientID %>');" />

//in code behind:
resetButton.DataBind();
```

.Net doesn't like literal writes inside server rendered controls other than panels.

Comment: In the second code area the onlick is a server event and 'return resetForm...' is there for not a valid assignment.

Comment: Well spotted - I've changed it to onclientclick

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using runat="server" you're better off setting this property in the code-behind anyway.

resetButton.attributes.add("onclick", ".....");

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an HTML encoding taking place for the string in resetForm.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but did you ensure that the file type is appropriate? I.e. jsp for a JSP or asp for an ASP?

This should be getting caught by the compiler before encoding.  Is it possible that there is pre-processing before compiling the page?  Your id is changed and it added a name element...